# Excel doesn't accept any IF statment

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I tried to use this statement

```
=IF(C15-E14<=0 ,"", C15-E14)
```

All I wanted was if the subtraction value is zero or negative then show blank, else show the subtraction result.

The excel always highlights the middle part **,"",** without giving instructions to fix the error

I formatted the cell to general but it didn't work

Comment: I have no problem using that exact formula. Perhaps it is a regional settings issue? Unicode problem? Hard to tell -- I can't reproduce the issue. Are you trying to insert the formula with VBA? Or -- are you just typing it in a cell?

Comment: make sure those cells are not formatted as text.  That may be causing the issue.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am trying to enter it in the cell directly...what problem may the regional setting cause and how to check it?

Comment: Try replacing the `,` with `;`

Comment: @ZackE it is formatted as general

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes that is the solution, it worked. thanks a lot.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?540900-RESOLVED-Excel-VBA-If-statement-Problem! this could also be the solution for other people looking in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `;` like:

```
=IF(C15-E14<=0; ""; C15-E14)
```